# Picker selection and translation conflict in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a movable VStack which carry a Picker. When I want chose deferent option from Picker I cannot, because SwiftUI thinks I want use DragGesture, therefor my Picker is lockdown! My DragGesture has **minimumDistance: 0** but it does not solve issue when I change this value also, from other hand I like to have **minimumDistance: 0** so it is not even an option for me to solving issue with increasing **minimumDistance**, so I need help to find a way, thanks.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        StyleView()
        
    }
}
```

---

```
struct StyleView: View {
    
    @State private var location: CGSize = CGSize()
    @GestureState private var translation: CGSize = CGSize()
    @State private var styleIndex: Int = 0
    let styles: [String] = ["a", "b", "c"]

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Picker(selection: $styleIndex, label: Text("Style")) {

                ForEach(styles.indices, id:\.self) { index in
                    
                    Text(styles[index].description)

                }
 
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            .padding()

            Text("selected style: " + styles[styleIndex])
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.red)
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .padding()
        .position(x: location.width + translation.width + 200, y: location.height + translation.height + 100)
        .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                    .updating($translation) { value, state, _ in
                        state = value.translation
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        location = CGSize(width: location.width + value.translation.width, height: location.height + value.translation.height)
                    })
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I know you say in your question you don't want any minimum distance, but are you *sure* it doesn't work for you -- setting it to `1` made the picker work for me and seems like a pretty minimal side effect. I'm not sure how it could ever be 0, since it would never be able to tell the difference between a drag and a tap.

Comment: I meant about drag on Picker, normally we can change Picker with drag, if even I chose 1 and as you said it is very small, but the drag on picker does not work, have you tried?

Comment: Ah -- I didn't understand that bit. Okay, got it.

Comment: for example if use **minimumDistance=200** it would solve the problem, but there is no good drag experience on VStack! the drag must be bigger than 200 to start dragging!

Answer (score 0):

DragGesture triggers when the user presses down on a view and move at least a certain distance away. So, this creates a picker with a drag gesture that triggers when the user moves it at least 10 points (it should be greater than 0 otherwise how can it know about the tap and the drag)

```
struct StyleView: View {
    
    @State private var location: CGSize = CGSize()
    @GestureState private var translation: CGSize = CGSize()
    @State private var styleIndex: Int = 0
    let styles: [String] = ["a", "b", "c"]

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Picker(selection: $styleIndex, label: Text("Style")) {

                ForEach(styles.indices, id:\.self) { index in
                    
                    Text(styles[index].description)

                }
 
            }.gesture(DragAndTapGesture(count: styles.count, selected: $styleIndex).horizontal)
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            .padding()
            Text("selected style: " + styles[styleIndex])
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.red)
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .padding()
        .position(x: location.width + translation.width + 200, y: location.height + translation.height + 100)
        .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 1)
                    .updating($translation) { value, state, _ in
                        state = value.translation
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        location = CGSize(width: location.width + value.translation.width, height: location.height + value.translation.height)
                    })
        
        
    }
}



struct DragAndTapGesture {
    var count: Int
    @Binding var selected: Int
    
    init(count: Int, selected: Binding<Int>) {
        self.count = count
        self._selected = selected
    }
    
    var horizontal: some Gesture {
        DragGesture().onEnded { value in
            if -value.predictedEndTranslation.width > UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, self.selected < self.count - 1 {
                self.selected += 1
            }
            if value.predictedEndTranslation.width > UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, self.selected > 0 {
                self.selected -= 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I meant about drag on Picker, normally we can change Picker with drag, if even I chose 10 and as you said it is small, but the drag on picker does not work, have you tried?

Comment: okay, I got it, see my edited answer. It might help you.

Comment: I see no deference, it does not solve the issue

Comment: have you checked now?

Comment: Have you checked on the device also, as I am easily able to drag as well as tap the picker and the value is also changing after drag. Increase the padding area, and change the background color of the picker so that it will be easily distinguishable.